# What kind of QT widget is the QGIS drawing area?

Tags: qgis, qt

I mean when open QGIS , and add a vector layer or other type of data. The content will show on the "Drawing Area", i want to ask, the drwaing area is some type of widget or just in the QMainWindow?

[image]

I download the qgis source code(1.8 or 1.9). and searche the src/ui/ folder, do not find any named similar to  "drawing "   *.ui file. And i use qt-creator and open the "qgisapp.ui" and judge by the size of the window, the drawing area is in this window. But i am not sure, because i am not familiar with qgis code.

[image]

What i want to do is want to mime QGIS to code little GIS drawing toy using Qt. So anyone could answer my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [QgsMapCanvas,](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html) which subclasses [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html).

You can browse the [source code for this class](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp) on github.

There is some developer documentation to introduce this class in the [PyQGIS cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html).

You can, of course, just re-use parts of QGIS, or enhance QGIS, rather than create your own application if you choose.

Comment: thx very much. YOur advices is very useful.  i just want to practise for understanding basic gis techniuqe

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, i searched the qgis code and found it there is a class which extended from QFrame, its name is QgsMapCanvas, it handle the rending things in qgis system.

Meanwhile, i searched the earliest qgis code.  the drawing area is a manually added Q3Frame(under QT3 times).

That's that.